# Fluent Validation and Ioc container: CreateInstance called many times in MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

In the MVC project im working I use Fluent Validation to implement some validation logics and I defined my `UnityValidatorFactory`  as following:

```
public class UnityValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityValidatorFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        if (_container.IsRegistered(validatorType))
        {
            return _container.Resolve(validatorType) as IValidator;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In global.asax i register my class like this:

```
var validationFactory = new UnityValidatorFactory(container); 
var fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider = new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(validationFactory);
```

I defined my validator for my viewmodel:

```
public class ServiceRequestViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ServiceRequestViewModel>
{
    public ServiceRequestViewModelValidator()
    {
        // many validation rules here...
    }   
}
```

I register my validator in unity:

```
container.RegisterType<IValidator<ServiceRequestViewModel>, ServiceRequestViewModelValidator>();
```

When i post data to the action with argument of type ServiceRequestViewModel the method CreateInstance is called so many times and the 
constructor of ServiceRequestViewModelValidator as well. 
Because the validatin rules I implemented are time consuming I don't wont they get executed more then one time. Moreover I don't understand why they are call more than one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later found out that this is how MVC works. In  MVC there are many place  where MVC needs to get the validator for example it tries to get metadata for each property, and calls into the provider for each one. 
Then to fix my problem I created my validators as singleton instances registering the validator in unity with  ContainerControlledLifetimeManager

```
container.RegisterType<IValidator<ServiceRequestViewModel>, ServiceRequestViewModelValidator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```